# Association of the words "to wear" in the given context

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Are the words "to wear" associated with all nouns starting from "patterns" in the following sentence?

> "Fashion is a never-ending cycle of new patterns, textures, materials
>   and shapes to wear."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, “to wear” refers to the new:

> patterns, texture, material an shapes

that the always evolving fashion industry is continuously suggesting for us to put on.